# MySQL throwing error 1064, doesn't seem to recognize OVER command

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My query is:

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ASC)
FROM submissions
```

The error message I receive is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY score ASC) FROM submissions LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

I am running this query in phpMyAdmin. I notice that OVER is not colored blue, nor does is it suggested as I type, unlike other command words (ORDER, ASC, etc).

This simpler query runs just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions
```

I've tried putting things in quotes, using the RANK function instead, and fiddling with whitespace, but the query still doesn't run. What is wrong here?

Comment: `OVER` is not supported until MySQL 8+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are running a version of MySQL which is earlier than 8+, one which does not support `ROW_NUMBER`.  There are a few options for simulating `ROW_NUMBER` in earlier versions of MySQL.  One is to use user variables:

```
SELECT *,
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rn
FROM submissions, (SELECT @row_number := 0) tmp
ORDER BY score;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. In your example, what is does `tmp` signify?

Comment: @Tumblewood Juergen added that (I missed it).  And think if you leave off `tmp`, which is a table _alias_, MySQL will complain with an error that "every derived table must have an alias."  It doesn't serve any functional purpose, but it needs to be there.